# Вложенные объекты JSON не десериализуются

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

Есть условный запрос:

```
{
  "parcelPackage": {
   ...какие-то поля
}
}
```

Если на метод контроллера приходит JSON такого формата, то при десириализация поля все null.

Если на вход приходит запрос такого формата:

```
{
  ...какие-то поля
}
```

Десириализация проходит корректно и поля имеют корректные значения, почему так?

Мне бы хотелось использовать первый вариант запроса.

Метод контроллера:

```
RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/createPackage")
    public CreatePackageParcelRs createPackage(@RequestBody final ParcelPackage parcelPackageRq) {
        final CreatePackageParcelRs response = new CreatePackageParcelRs();
        if (parcelPackageRq != null) {
            packageService.createOrUpdatePackage(parcelPackageRq);
            response.setResultCode("200");
            response.setResultDescription("Success");
        } else {
            response.setResultCode("400");
            response.setResultDescription("Bad Request");
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что структура

```
{
    "parcelPackage": {
        ...какие-то поля
    }
}
```

будет верна в том случае, если Ваш объект типа `ParcelPackage` будет входит в другой объект:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/createPackage")
public CreatePackageParcelRs createPackage(@RequestBody SomeObject someObject) {
    ...
}

public class SomeObject {

    private ParcelPackage parcelPackage;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Изучите более подробно структуру JSON. `{} (фигурные скобки)` - обозначют **ОБЪЕКТ** в структуре `JSON`. Когда вы пишите их - это уже означает начало объекта (даже если нет имени). Посему, используя нерабочий вариант вашей структуры, вы отсылает контроллеру **ОБЪЕКТ В ОБЪЕКТЕ**, а в контроллере принимаете просто один **ОБЪЕКТ** и из-за этого получаете `null`, потому что внутри объекта `ParcelPackage` нет никакого `parcelPackage`